# WP8 + WolfframAPI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, wolframalpha

I'm trying to use the Wolfram Library on a WP8 app, and am getting this error, as soon as it gets into the function that uses it, before it even starts the function.

> Type 'WolframAPI.WAResult' from assembly 'WolframAPI,
>   Version=1.2.4112.34755,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is
>   attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.

I'm not sure I understand what's causing this error, and if there is anyway around it or if it is simply not useable in WP8?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure I understand what's causing this error

The last part of the error explicit says what's causing it:

> attempting to implement an inaccessible interface

In short: The API isn't compatible with WP8, and is attempting to use reflection of private types, which isn't allowed on Windows Phone.